# Is it possible to be able to change an array using the input of a user?

Tags: java, arrays

My teacher gave us an assignment to create a building directory made up of offices and their floors using a string array. After that she told us the user should be able to search the directory for a business, make changes to the directory, view the directory and save changes to a file. I am stuck on how to allow the user to change the elements in an array as we never did it in class and I can't seem to find it in any of my text books. Please help :') .. here is the code I have so far:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Townsendtest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //String array of businesses on each floor starting at floor 0-24
        String floor [] = { "Ground Floor", "Advanced Technologies", "HiMark Marketing",
            "Law Offices of John Daniels", "PST Systems", "Century United Brokers Inc.",
            "Creative Resources", "Design Centre Associates", "Ideal Media Group",
            "SF Net Developers", "Shears Medical Services Inc.",
            "Green Space Construction Inc.", "Cornerstone Mortgage Capital",
            "Allied Advantage Realty", "JAMS the Resolution Experts",
            "Law Offices of Matt Dill", "Vacant", "The Drop in Centre",
            "Artisan Interiors Consultancy", "NGS Group",
            "Robert  H. Greene Real Estate", "Vacant", "Vacant",
            "Denise A. Patterson Attorney at Law", "Conference Rooms 1-6" };

        String namefind;

        System.out.print("Enter the name of the Business: ");
        namefind = businessname.nextLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < floor.length; i++){

            if(namefind.equalsIgnoreCase(floor[i])) {
                System.out.println("Business Found!");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        //if business is not found, it will assume the user needs to see the entire building directory
        System.out.println("Business not found, try again.\nHere is the directory:");


        //prints the Floor Number of index and he Business listed on the floor
        System.out.println("Floor Number\t\tBusiness");

        //for loop to print entire index to the user
        for(int counter=0; counter<floor.length; counter++ ) {
            System.out.println(counter + "\t\t\t" + floor[counter]);
        }//end for loop

    }//end main
}//end class
```

Comment: try searching on internet  , each element of array is same as variable, have you ever updated any variable from user input, it same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To modify the contents of an array, simply use:

```
floor[i] = "Some new data";
```

In this case, `i` is the index i.e. the counter. Arrays start with the index `0`.

However, the program terminates as soon as the input matches since you're invoking `System.exit`. You probably need to put that in a loop the keep the program alive.

So, for your exact problem this may be a solution:

```
if(namefind.equalsIgnoreCase(floor[i])) {
    System.out.print("Enter the NEW name of the Business: ");
    floor[i] = businessname.nextLine();

    // Do NOT System.exit - wrap the whole thing in a loop.
}
```

Comment: The OP is NOT updating the array of businesses - this should be constant/immutable.
They are looking for (searching) for a business on the floors...

Comment: @GermannArlington - sorry for the confusion. The OP asked: *"I am stuck on how to allow the user to change the elements in an array"* so that is simply what I tried to answer.

Comment: I know you can change the elements in the array by using this but how do you change the elements in the array with the user's input?

Comment: Couldn't you simply invoke: `String newName = scanner.nextLine();` again (for a new name) and set `floor[i] = newName;`? If you do the `System.exit` call the program will terminate. If the operations are to be repeated some kind of loop is required.

Answer (score 0):

It would make more sense to use

```
if(floor[i].contains(namefind)) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.. however, I asked how does one change the array using the user's input.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from your question, I'd say you are asking:

1. how to read user input
2. how to put that in an array

To read user input from the standard input, I'd use something like this:

```
BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String input = inputReader.readLine();
```

This will read the user input until a newline character.

To assign the variable's value to an array element, you should be able to do something like this:

```
array[0] = input;
```

Also, a simple Google search gives you many solutions readily available for the problem: 
https://www.google.com/search?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=java%20read%20user%20input%20into%20array